# VLC resets preferences and interface customizations after updating

Tags: windows-10, vlc-media-player

This has happened more than once. Is there any way to stop it? Or any way to back them up at least? Using Windows 10.

Comment: It's happened to me as well. With the update to 3.0.12 today, and with 3.0.11 in June. Also on Windows 10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't run into this problem with losing my settings, but you should be able to back up your preferences by simply making a copy of `C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Roaming\vlc` (or equivalent location on your machine).

To restore your settings, first make sure VLC isn't running, and then just replace that folder with your backup copy.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you mean updating VLC, not Windows. 
In that case, rather than use the VLC installer,

- [download](https://download.videolan.org/pub/videolan/vlc/last/win64/) the:

  - .Zip compressed ver or the
  - .7Z version or the
  - .exe "installer"
- Open the file in a utility such as 7-Zip [Yes, even the *installer* executable is compressed, and can be unpacked!].
- Drag everything (except the *$PLUGINSDIR* in the installer) into the *C:\Program Files (x86)\VideoLAN\VLC* folder (or other destination). You will need to do this as Administrator and answer *Yes* to *Overwrite current files?"

This should not affect preferences, whether stored locally or in the Registry. However, manually updating *does* have a small risk that some current setting may not work well with the new version. That said, I've never had an issue using manual update.

The screenshot below shows the unpacked installer.

[image: VLC installer in 7-Zip]